# Regressive n log(n) sorting

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting

I have a sorting algorithm that requires performing an `n log n` sort `n` times, with n decrementing by 1 in each step?  In other words: I would expect a performance of `O(n log n + (n-1) log (n-1) + (n-2) log (n - 2) + ... )`.  This problem definitely doesn't strike me as something that hasn't been encountered before so I must ask:

**What is the order-of-magnitude performance of an `n log n` sort `n` times, with n decrementing by 1 in each step?**

Comment: Wow, I was surprised to learn that the sum is equal to `Log2(H(N))`, where `H` defines [*hyperfactorial*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html), whatever the heck it is :-) How do I know? [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+i*log2%28i%29%2C+i+from+1+to+N) to the rescue.

Comment: so how did you uncover that this is "hyperfactorial"?  What was the query that you used in Wolfram Alpha?  I actually have been attempting to use Wolfram Alpha to figure this out, as well :-)

Comment: @RyanDelucchi: This should be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Hyperfactorial

Comment: The link to alpha in my first comment points to the query.

Comment: Yes, I see the query now.  Wow: this is an interesting result indeed.  I'm beginning to think that I should reconsider my algorithm :-)

Comment: Ignoring your actual question, why do you have to sort this more than once? Maybe you can use that information to devise a better algorithm for your data?

Comment: The only time I've seen progressive sorting done is with the alias method for storing finite discrete distributions but that sort can actually be replaced with one or two logN insertions. Or there are other even more efficient aliasing methods.

Comment: I am basically trying to sort a set of line segments (defined by long-lat coordinates) in the correct order ... that is the order in which they reside along a curve.  The algorithm I was looking into would involve a.) extract a line segment off S b.) sorting the remaining ones based on their distance away from (a) ... c.)  iterate on a until S is empty.  I realize this is a very naive approach but I didn't actually realize it was *that* poor.  I am currently looking for alternatives (any suggestions are greatly welcomed).

Comment: @doomster  I have just posted the original problem that lead to this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823517/sorting-geographical-non-contiguous-line-segments-along-an-implied-curve

Comment: can we use the standard n(n+1)/2 and multiply by the nlogn?  that would be O(n**3logn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Time = SUM { k log k } for k: 1..n = log(H(n)) ~ Θ(log(H(n)))
```

*H(n): Hyper-Factorial function in n*

**Asymptotic Approximation:**

I'll try to deduce f(n) as an approximation for an upper bound, by generalizing k ..

```
f(n) = log n * SUM { k } for k: 1..n

f(n) = log n * 1/2 n (n+1)

f(n) = 1/2 n log n (n+1)

O(f(n)) = O(1/2 n^2 log n (n+1))

~ O(n^2 log n)
```

I'll try to deduce g(n) as an approximation for a lower bound, by generalizing log(k) ..

```
g(n) = n * SUM { log(k) } for k: 1..n

g(n) = n * log(1/2 n(n+1))

g(n) = n * (log(1/2) + log(n) + log(n+1))

g(n) = n * (c + log(n) + log(n+1))

g(n) = n * (c + log(n(n+1)))

Ω(g(n)) = Ω(n * (c + log(n^2+n))) = Ω(n * log(n^2+n))

~ Ω(n log(n^2+n))
```

So, we have:

```
Ω(n log(n^2+n)) < Θ(log(H(n))) < O(n^2 log n)
```

Example:

```
n = 100; Ω(922.02) < Θ(20,756.7) < O(46,051.7)

n = 1000; Ω(1.38 × 10^4) < Θ(3.2 × 10^6) < O(6.9 × 10^6)
```

**Note**: f(n) and g(n) are asymptotic approximation for bounds, they're not accurate ..

Answer (score 2):

N^2 log(N)

You are doing a NlogN operation N times so N times NlogN is the solution.

Oh after your edit it's quite different. It's very hard to figure out that summation but it's upper bound (which is all big O is) is still N^2 log(N). You may be able to figure out a closer upper bound but I think that would be a viable solution.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135787/asymptotic-formula-for-the-logarithm-of-the-hyperfactorial for a much more exact solution.

The much more exact solution is still bounded above by N^2 logN (by quite a bit) so I think it is still a safe upper bound.

Comment: Yes, my edit changes things a bit :-) ... I realize that the upper bound is N^2 log N (which sucks).  But, I wonder if the "decrement by 1 in each step" causes this to amortize to something much better?

Comment: +1 The link to math actually shows that n^2 log n is tight in the sense that there is no non-constant factor to get rid off.

Answer (score 1):

It's about 0.5 * n<sup>2</sup> * log(n):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX 100
double sum[1 + MAX];

int main(void)
{
  int i;

  sum[0] = 0;

  for (i = 1; i <= MAX; i++)
  {
    sum[i] = sum[i - 1] + i * ceil(log2(i));
    printf("%i %.0f %.0f\n", i, sum[i], ceil(log2(i) * i * i / 2));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/PRpX9r)):

```
1 0 0
2 2 2
3 8 8
4 16 16
5 31 30
6 49 47
7 70 69
8 94 96
9 130 129
10 170 167
...
90 25871 26293
91 26508 26946
92 27152 27608
93 27803 28279
94 28461 28959
95 29126 29647
96 29798 30344
97 30477 31050
98 31163 31764
99 31856 32488
100 32556 33220
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `Theta(N^2 log N)`.

It's obviously `O(N^2 log N)`.

To show that it's `Omega(N^2 log N)`, consider only the big half of the sequence, where each value of `k` is at least `N/2`. For simplicity, assume that `N` is even.

```
Sum[k=1..N](k log k) >= Sum[k=N/2..N](k log k)           ; drop the small half
                     >= Sum[k=N/2..N]((N/2) log (N/2))   ; since each k >= N/2
                     >= N/2 * N/2 * log (N/2)
                      = N^2/4 * (log N - log 2)
                      = N^2/4 * logN - c
                      ∈ Omega(N^2 log N)
```