# Sorting Geographical non-contiguous line segments along an implied curve

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, geometry, line, graph-theory

**Given:**

A Set (for the sake of discussion we will call it `S`), which is an ***unordered*** collection of line segments.  Each line segment is defined as two Longitude-Latitude end-points.  While all of the line segments follow an implied curve, there are "gaps" between each of the segments, of various sizes.  We refer to this curve as *"implied"* because it is not explicitly defined anywhere.  The only information that we have available are the line segments contained within `S`.

**Desired Result:**

A sequence (for the sake of discussion we will call it `R`), which is an ***ordered*** collection of line segments. Each line segment is defined just as before, following the same implied curve as before but are now **sorted by their position along the implied curve**.

**Context (i.e. "Why in the heck do I need this?"):**

Basically I have incomplete geographical data that needs to be *normalized* and "completed" by doing some very simple interpolation to form a complete curve with *no* gaps.  You might ask "why not just fit a curve to all the line segment end-points and be done with it?" -- well, that's not quite what I am after.  The line segments are precisely where they should be located, and there is no need for the final curve to be "smooth".  In fact, I intend to connect each of the segments with a straight-line (the crudest form of interpolation imaginable).  But, connecting the segments is easy; the hard part is sorting them.

**So In Summary: What would be a performant algorithm for going from `S` to `R`?**

Comment: Could the curve be anything? Maybe you can post an image of what `S` looks like?

Comment: Imagine a Hiking trail: and you basically have it.  Very tight bends are not likely to be apart of the curve and assume that sharp corners don't exist at all.

Comment: Did you think about simply getting the shortest distance from a point on a line segment to a point on another line segment? And the line segment with the shortest distance to the original point would be the next segment in R. This would probably be n^2. Too slow?

Comment: I would hope that I can do better than O(n^2)

Comment: @RyanDelucchi: hiking trail from the side or from the top?  If side, then everything could be ordered by x axis, but I think your problem must be tougher, right? You are trying to find the combination of segments such as the curve comes out to be the least crazy, right?

Comment: The curve is fixed and the segments are at specific locations (in other words: the curve and line segments are already pre-defined).  What I am trying to do is to determine what *order* these segments are in along the curve.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) or a [cover tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree) to find nearby points quickly.

If you need one continuous curve, I would suggest that a short [traveling salesman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) path that incorporates the given edges would be a reasonable reconstruction. You could use [2-opt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-opt) together with a k-d tree the way [Bentley described](http://joc.journal.informs.org/content/4/4/387.abstract) (paywalled, sorry; I think there's also a description in [this chapter on TSP local search by Johnson and McGeoch](http://www2.research.att.com/~dsj/papers/TSPchapter.pdf)). The one modification needed would be to ensure that the initial path includes the given edges and that 2-opt moves do not remove those edges.

Comment: The k-d tree is sounding like a great approach.  As for connecting the segments, I honestly think that just doing a direct edge might actually be sufficient for my situation (since gaps in the data is a very strong indicator that accuracy is less important).  It turns out that I am already subdividing my surface region using a constant-time bucketing scheme, so I have the option of confining k-trees into a single bucket (or a span of buckets).  This would create an upper bound on the size of these k-d trees.  I will look into it and report back later.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the implied curve has two properties. One is it is continious which means there is no segments. Second, its first derivative is continious which means there is no corners.

From second property we can say that if the angle between two line is closer to each other, they are more related. But i guess it is not enough. You can define a cost function which depends on the angle between lines and distance of lines.

**C = A*angle + B*distance** (where A,B should be tested and tuned)

Form this function you can find how much each line is related to another one. Than you can just simply connect the line with the strongest relations. Though i guess greedy algorithm does not mean you will always get the optimal solution.

Comment: This is actually quite similar to one of my earlier ideas but there are really two problems with this: 1.) you are still left with the problem of computing the distance between each pair of segments  2.) The angle between the line segments doesn't correlate to whether the line segments should be connected or not

Comment: I dont agree with you about the angles. They are giving a hint but their meaning is lost quickly with distance increasing. So to find the right cost function is problem and it may not be linear as i say. About the complexity general rule: if n is not high which most of time not, dont care :) But if n is high you should check space partioning algorithms my favorite is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_%28computational_geometry%29 O(1) in best case.

Comment: I'm actually dealing with an utterly massive set of data so n is pretty darn high (think OpenStreetMap data ;-)).  But, you make a good point on the angle being more meaningful within short distances.  Since I am using also segmenting space via a constant-time bucketing scheme, your idea of incorporating angles may actually prove very helpful within these buckets.  It's looking like the kd-tree is a strong candidate for solving this.

Comment: I actually had to throw this project on the back-burner (was working on other stuff) but now I am looking into it again and I'm leaning more towards a "Bin" algorithm, and I may even factor in angle and distance after all ... more to follow :-)